# Rails 3 simultaneously rendering response of more than one action of a controller in another controller's view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, controller, actionmethod

Using **Rails v 3.0.11, Ruby v 1.9.3**

I have a page having link "Reports" on it, clicking on which invokes **ReportsController#index**

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Renders index.html.haml
  end
end
```

Now I have an already existing JSON API (**ReportsDataController** shown below) returning JSON response which I need to reuse.

*A Controller returning JSON response (my JSON API)*

```
class ReportsDataController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def users_events_activity
    user_activity_data_obj = find_user_events_activity_per_day
    respond_with user_activity_data_obj
  end

  def users_comments_activity
    user_comments_data_obj = find_user_comments_activity_per_day
    respond_with user_comments_data_obj
  end

end
```

On my **app/views/reports/index.html.haml** I need to simultaneously render the data returned by 
actions **ReportsDataController#users_events_activity** and **ReportsDataController#users_comments_activity**.

*Is there a Rails standard way by which the above mentioned requirement can be achieved? If not can anybody please suggest me some approaches to achieve the same?*

Thanks,

Jignesh

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make two requests, you can always create another controller action and render the JSON like this:

```
class ReportsDataController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def users_combined_events_comments_activity
    user_activity_data_obj = find_user_events_activity_per_day
    user_comments_data_obj = find_user_comments_activity_per_day
    respond_with { activities: user_activity_data_obj, comments: user_comments_data_obj }
  end
end
```

Comment: But how do I invoke my JSON API from ReportsController#index action?

Comment: I would use this method itself as index action.